# I want to use javascript to resize my browser so that it doesn't scroll

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I want to use a background color with Gradient on the intro page, but when I shrink my browser, I want to work to reduce the height value without scrolling.
I don't know what method to use when it's resizing.

The code is as follows.

```
function __screenResize () {
    var innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var availHeight = window.screen.availHeight;
    document.getElementById('section').style.height = innerHeight + 'px';
    window.onresize = function () {
      document.getElementById('section').style.height = availHeight + 'px';
    }
}
```

Comment: Go look at the `vh` unit in CSS, this probably doesn’t need any scripting to begin with.

Comment: We're going to JavaScript because of cross-browsing issues.

Comment: What issues? // Right now, you only have a function - are you asking / trying to ask, how to automatically call it, when a resize of the browser window occurs? For that, you need to add an event handler then, in the most basic way that can be done as shown here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize

Comment: _"cross-browsing issues"_ like what? [Viewport units are even supported in IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)